# RoR - Windows host, Vagrant/Ubuntu guest; having trouble accessing localhost on host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ubuntu, vagrant

I recently updated my Ubuntu version in Vagrant from 12.xx to 14.04 and have also updated Guest Additions. I use VirtualBox and SSH into my development VM which primarily is used for Rails applications. The Rails server is listening on port 3000 which is also configured in the Vagrantfile as shown:

`# config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000`

I have tried accessing 127.0.0.1:3000, localhost:3000, 10.0.2.2, tried using different ports, added exceptions to my Windows firewall, ran this:

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1022 -j ACCEPT`

I also tried different servers such as Unicorn and Thin in lieu of WEBrick rails server. I destroyed this VM and rebuilt/installed everything as well as upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 yet again. I'm not sure why Windows won't display my stuff! Any ideas will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance. :-)

Comment: Is it accessible over SSH? Is there another VM running that could be using the same port? Are you also running or have you run another Rail app on the host while the VM was running?

Comment: Does your network setup look like this? http://imgur.com/xqTGFuv

Comment: Yes Ian, it looks exactly like that.

Comment: I have a feeling Guest Additions may be broken on your guest OS, check that /etc/sudoers contains:
`vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` and 
`Defaults:vagrant !requiretty` also try updating your guest additions. Also try `sudo apt-get install dkms` and `/etc/init.d/vboxadd setup`

Comment: I have dkms installed, I ran the vboxadd setup command, and I already have those two lines within sudoers. Running `vagrant up` still returns problems with syncing my folder to the Windows folder. The `mkdir -p /vagrant` and `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` are returned after running vagrant up.